# Unable to connect MySQL DB, getting ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I tried to connect the DB via MySQL Java Script as below:

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');  
 var con = mysql.createConnection({  
   host: "******",
   user: "******",
   password: "******"
 });  
 con.connect(function(err) {  
 if (err) throw err;  
   console.log("Connected!");
 });
```

And I'm using Node to execute, While I execute the above program getting the below error message:

```
if (err) throw err;
       ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED XX.XXX.XX.XXX:3306
  at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
  at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
```

Also I have pinged my ip address (ping XX.XXX.XX.XXX) and can able to get the response. Can help me to connect the DB.

Comment: Are your credentials correct?

Comment: Yes, Via SQL Developer I can able to connect...

Comment: Your host must be your localhost ip, eg: 127.0.0.1 (Only if Mysql is installed on your own machine)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the error resolved by adding the socketPath parameter

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock', 
    database: 'dbname'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, But how can I find my socketPath?

Comment: Which os you use ?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: I have linux and the socketPath was /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock, I searched a little about windows but I did nod find something. But by reading again https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql, I think that you could use instead host and port

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest creating a connectionPool to save your resources. Here is how I did it:

```
//import settings.js
const db_config = {
    hostname : "localhost",
    user : settings.user, //username
    password : settings.password, //password
    database : settings.database //db
}

//create db connection pool
const con = mysql.createPool(db_config);
```

So the next step is to use that connection pool! Don't be scared about the async/bluebird nature of this code, it's just how I built it.

```
async function query(sql, params) {
    const connection = await con.getConnectionAsync();
    return connection.queryAsync(sql,params)
        .then(rows => rows)
        .finally(() => connection.release());
}
```

This is grabbing the connection `getConnection` method (Async is from bluebird promisifying the method), and using the `query` method (async'd), and then finally releasing the connection back into the pool. This helps save you from memory leaks caused by unclosed TCP connections.

Make sure that you also specify the port if you have changed it from the default MySQL port as well.